# Is there a way to insert charts programmatically via Google Docs API?

Tags: api, charts, google-api, documentation, google-apis-explorer

I want to create a couple of google docs with embedded charts coming from a google spreadsheet. Is there a way to insert those charts programmatically utilizing Google Docs API?